# Blank screen after installation, please help!

Tags: release-loki, boot

I reinstalled Elementary and after install it asks me to restart, and when it restarts a blank screen. I clicked esc, arrow down and up as suggested in other threads, no help. I reinstalled it the second time, maybe something went wrong. Same result. Then I reinstalled it with USB drive because the first two install was from DVD. Same result. I was able to install Elementary couple of months ago and I'm using the same (latest) image. What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting the blank screen and how can I fix it?

Update: 4th installation with the same result, tried to untick some options at the installation process (like third party software), it did not help.

Comment: Are you using a (U)EFI-BIOS ? Maybee https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/25935/24281 can help you too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing with the default partitioning option? I had the same issue with Loki 0.4.1 until I used the default "erase everything" option and it installed fine.

I had separate ext4 partitions for `/`, `/home` and swap. Also tried adding a separate `/boot` but that didn't help either. The default option creates the following scheme:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disklabel type: dos
Device      Boot    Size    Type
/dev/sda1   *       57.7G   Linux
/dev/sda2           2G      Extended
/dev/sda5           2G      Linux swap / Solaris
```

I don't know what the deal is with sda2 because it's not mounted and does not show up with blkid:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1:  TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5:  TYPE="swap"
```

I wonder if it's a bug in the installer, I will investigate further and update the answer.

Comment: Well this issue didn't occur at installation, just randomly yesterday, Are you suggesting I should try the code above? (Sorry, I may not be that advanced with terminal)

Comment: The commands above would just show you details of your partitioning scheme, they wouldn't make any changes to your system - can't help or harm. Your issue is probably different because mine was related to a problem with (an old version of) the installer.

Comment: I see. So I reinstalled.ans it worked for a couple of days. Then one day it asks me to insert hoot device... I ended up reinstalling elementary. Now after reinstalling I restarted like x2. Third time restart it doesn't let me log in... Session returned error code 1. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem istalling version 6. In my case is was a bios error that caused the the isuse. Check if you have ACPI options that you can disable during build installation. In my case it solved the problem.